# Dynamically determine layout based on AuthorizeFilter and AllowAnonymous attribute in ASP.NET Core site

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My ASP.NET Core 3.1 site has two layouts. One for authenticated users called "_Layout.Authenticated" and one for unauthenticated users called "_Layout.Unauthenticated". Rather than using ViewStart.cshtml to specify the default layout to the one used the most and then specifying the layout for the other views on the views themselves I want the site to dynamically determine this.

I do have a solution using action filters and wanted to see if there is a better approach.

I created a custom action filter which will set a ViewData item with the layout name as follows:

```
public class LayoutSelectionActionFilterAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        ActionExecutedContext resultContext = await next().ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (resultContext.Result is ViewResult viewResult)
        {
            viewResult.ViewData["LayoutName"] = HasAllowAnonymous(context)
                ? "_Layout.Unauthenticated"
                : "_Layout.Authenticated";
        }
    }

    private static bool HasAllowAnonymous(FilterContext context)
    {
        IList<IFilterMetadata> filters = context.Filters;

        if (filters.OfType<IAllowAnonymousFilter>().Any())
        {
            return true;
        }

        Endpoint endpoint = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();

        return endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null;
    }
}
```

My ViewStart.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
    Layout =  ViewData["LayoutName"] as string;
}
```

Finally, I set up my filters in Startup.cs as follows:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
     AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
          .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
          .Build();

     options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(authorizationPolicyBuilder));
     options.Filters.Add(new LayoutSelectionActionFilterAttribute());
 });
```

Comment: As you did, achieving it with a action filter is ok. And using a result filter would be also fine.

Comment: @FeiHan thanks for the confirmation.